# Does Ribbon dynamic tabs exist in Delphi 2010?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, ribbon

I am writing an application with ribbon in Delphi. I don't know what are these tabs called technically, but is there any way that I can have tabs that are added when a condition is met and have a different color? 
Just like the one when you insert a shape in Word 2007 ("Format" tab) that comes at the end of all the tabs and is dynamic (appears in run-time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We looked at this when the Ribbon control was first introduced in Delphi. They were not supported in the original ribbon control with Delphi, but I haven't checked to see if they are supported in newer versions.

We looked at the Ribbon controls from DevExpress and TMS, and adopted the TMS cxomponents, as theirs was the only one (at that time) that supported the feature.

Looking at their websites, TMS shows this feature being used. Check the [TMS AdvToolBar component](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advtoolbar.asp). DevExpress' `TdxRibbon` implements it with the `Contexts` property.

Answer (score 2):

They are called "Context Tabs", and if I'm not mistaken, they are not supported currently.